# Simple key combo in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking to catch simple key combos such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. Here's my stab at it:

```
var isCtrl = false;
$(window).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 17) isCtrl = true;
    if (isCtrl && e.keyCode == 65) alert('hi');
});
```

Is this a good and robust approach? If not, how can I improve on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, try to utilize what the library provides to normalize the keystrokes .ctrlKey and .which:

```
if (e.which == 17 && e.ctrlKey) alert('hi');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `e.ctrlKey` instead of `isCtrl`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first stab looks good -- just remember to set `isCtrl` back to false on `keyup` (if `e.keyCode == 17` again).